# String matching using regex for array of items in a document in mongodb collection

Tags: regex, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I want to make a universal search where I search the db with a given `text` for a particular company. I have a products collection with each document having following fields

```
{
  _id: '',
  company: 'Amazon'
  category: 'Apparels',
  category1: 'Boys',
  tags: ['cotton', 'linen', 'handwash'], // random length array
  attribute: 'Style'
}.... many more such documents
```

**input fields:**

```
text = 'cotton'
name ='Amazon'
```

I have tried the following query to search any match for the given text in **category, category1, tags, attribute**

**Query**

```
db.products.aggregate([
   {
         $match: { 
            "company": 'Amazon',
            $or: [
              {"attribute": { $regex: text, $options: "i"}},
              {"category": { $regex: text, $options: "i" }},
              {"category1": { $regex: text, $options: "i" }},
              {"tags": { $regex: text, $options: "i" }}
            ]
          } 
       }
]);
```

I am not sure if this works for array **tags**, is this the correct way to **compare regex against all array items?**

***Note**: I do not want to use find queries, pure aggregation is needed*

Comment: HAve you tried https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same However, the following may give you better solution.

```
 let text = 'Style'
let name = 'Amazon'
let regexString = "^" + text + "$";
db1.products.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "company": name,
            $or: [
                { "attribute": { $regex: regexString } },
                { "category": { $regex: regexString } },
                { "category1": { $regex: regexString } },
                { "tags": { $regex: regexString } },
            ]
        }
    }
]).toArray()
    .then(re => res.json({ result: re }))
    .catch(err => res.json(err));
```

This will match exactly the same text. if you use `^` it will search for strings starting with the particular text and `$` will search for strings ending with text value.